# How to draw sequence diagram include BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, uml

I am having problem in drawing sequence diagram. For example, I have 1 class Activity and 1 class BroadcastReceiver. Then in class Activity I sendBroadcast(intent) that the BroadcastReceiver can receive. So how to draw it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Draw it in what? UML?

Comment: @Rarw Sequence diagram in UML2

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html) which has some good sequence diagram examples. I would probably treat the broadcast as a message being sent between classes. The broadcasting activity would the sender and those listening would be the receiver. I'm not sure how your `BroadcastReceiver` is set up but if it is implemented in the activities or classes that are listening this approach makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Sequence Diagram is to illustration how and in what order the objects cooperate with each other.

In Android, BroadcastReceiver is just a receiver, most of the time it would not care about who and in what condition broadcast an intent.

So, my suggestion is: Skip the activity who broadcast the intent, but focus on what happen since the moment that this broadcast receiver receives the intent.